# does spring uses request parameter to initialize request model domain object using @modelAttribute annotation

Tags: spring-mvc

I am getting `org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException` for request parameter passed in method arguments. Everything works fine even after this exception.This is captured on DynaTrace console while performance testing.Here is my controller method:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = UrlConstants.ES_UPDATE_APPLICABLE_ITEM, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void updateApplicableItem(@ModelAttribute("sessionDto") final SessionDTO sessionDto,
        @RequestParam(value = GdrConstants.REWARD_ID) final Long rewardId,
        @RequestParam(value = GdrConstants.APPL_ITEM_ID) final Long itemId,
        @RequestParam(value = GdrConstants.COLUMN_NAME) final String columnName,
        @RequestParam(value = GdrConstants.COLUMN_VALUE) final String columnValue,
        final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Model model) {
```

}

sessionDto is Domain object bind with html form using `@ModelAttribute`. On Dynatrace session i can see below exception:-

```
Invalid property 'itemId' of bean class [com.cisco.gdr.dto.SessionDTO]: 
    Bean property 'itemId' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the
    parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Same exception is thrown for other request parameter also i.e. rewardId,ItemId,coulnName and columnValue.

1. Does this imply that spring using request parameter to initialize sessionDto object and requires setter method for all input parameters even though these are not related to domain object?
2. Do we need getter also along with setter ?

If Yes then how can we prevent this and what is other better approach.I don't want this parameters to be used in initialization.

Point to note that UI is still loading properly and this captured only in Dynatrace tool and required to fix.

****Adding SessionDTO ***

// @Component(value = "sessionDto")
// @Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)
public class SessionDTO {

```
private final Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 * Adds the given attribute key and value to the session DTO. If the given attribute key already exists, it will be
 * overridden with the new value.
 * 
 * @param key
 * @param value
 */
public void addAttribute(final String key, final Object value) {
    this.attributes.put(key, value);
}

/**
 * Removes the given attribute key and its value from the session DTO.
 * 
 * @param key
 */
public void removeAttribute(final String key) {
    this.attributes.remove(key);
}

/**
 * Returns the attribute for the given key.
 * 
 * @param key
 * @return
 */
public Object getAttribute(final String key) {
    return this.attributes.get(key);
}

/**
 * Returns all the attributes added in the session DTO.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
    return this.attributes;
}
```

}

@DirkLachowski, 
Hi Dirk,I have edited post to add sessionDTO in it.I am not using form posting here.I am making an ajax call to this controller method.SeesionDto is not form object,its @modelSessionAttribute.I am just extracting some information from this which is required in business logic.I am suspicious that using @ModelAttribute as request parameter without form binding is creating problem. 
Thank you-Junaid

Comment: Please show your `SessionDTO` and the sending form.